# WCF not deserializing value types. Mysterious behaviour

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, c#-4.0

Service Code :

```
[ServiceContract]
    public interface IServices
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [XmlSerializerFormat]
        GetProductsResponse Getproducts(GetProductsRequest productsrequest);

    [OperationContract]
    SaveProductsResponse SaveProducts1(SaveProductsRequest1 productsrequest);
} 


public class GetProductsRequest
{
    [XMLElement]
    public string id;

    [XMLElement,typeof(Person)]
    public Person[] Persons;
}

[DataContract]
public class SaveProductsRequest1
{
    [DataMember]
    public List<Person> Persons;
}


[DataContract]
public class Person
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Id;

    [DataMember]
    public string Name;

    [DataMember]
    public Sex Sex;
}

[DataContract]
public enum Sex
{
    [EnumMember]
    Male,
    [EnumMember]
    Female
}
```

Client :

```
ServicesClient client = new ServicesClient();
SaveProductsRequest1 req = new SaveProductsRequest1();
req.Persons = new List<Person> { new Person { Id = 10, Name = "Al", Sex = Sex.Female} }.ToArray();

client.SaveProducts1(req);
```

I am able to get the value 'Al'(string) at the service side. But the values 10 and Male(value types) are reset to default (0 and Male) at service side.

This only happens when I have XmlSerializerFormat for any one of my method in the service contract(GetProducts in this case) and inside my GetProducts class when I put XMLElement for any array property and one additional string property.

Is it issue with WCF runtime?

Comment: Please include the Person class

Comment: can we see how `Person` is declared please?

Comment: how do the datacontract look like?

Comment: hmm... your `Person` class cant be complete. It must be missing `Sex` data member

Comment: @Al.Net where is `Sex` ? My concern is that we'd be chasing an issue that isn't present in the obviously-different version of the class we're shown

Comment: Should you really have `[Serializable]` *and* `[DataContract]`? I only every use `[DataContract]` with my WCF-serialised classes.

Comment: Copy past issue, Sorry Now included.

Comment: But eventhough i dont have serializable I am getting issue. Let me edit it. So that some one can re produce the same issue

Comment: @Al.Net: I dont think you need both `Serializable` and `DataContract`. Drop the `Serializable` attribute

Comment: @John But eventhough i dont have serializable I am getting issue

Comment: @Al.Net are there any other things in `Person` that you haven't shown? any `[DefaultValue(...)]`? or any `ShouldSerialize*` methods? or `*Specified` properties?

Comment: can someone here re-produce the same issue?

Comment: Any working answer would be more helpful please

Comment: @Al.Net: I hope you generated the proxy after you had fully defined your service contracts and data contracts (and re-built your project as well). I just dont see anything here that would make things fail

Comment: @John: Yes I have latest genereate proxy. I am 100% sure that this doesnt work. My colleague also tried the same and getting the issue.

Comment: @Al.Net what .NET version? it works fine here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've setup a test WCF service using your server-side code, and a test client again using your example client-side code, and it works fine:

[image]

As you can see, 1 `Person` was transmitted with all 3 values intact. If there is something different happening at your end, it *may* be related to configuration options in your config file, but fundamentally: the code works. I'm testing using .NET 4.5

Comment: Shall i see your servicecontract? Because My code is also working fine. The problem comes only when one of my method has[XMLSerialzeFormat] attribute(in my case, It is Getproducts). Please post your service contract and its operation contracts and its class members

Comment: @Al.Net I have exactly the code from your question; all I changed from the question was to add dummy stubs for the other 3 types: `[DataContract] public class SaveProductsResponse { }`, `[DataContract] public class GetProductsRequest { }` and `[DataContract] public class GetProductsResponse { }`. For info I've also tested it without the `[DataContract]` on the 2 "products" related types - it still works fine.

Comment: let me also try new sample Marc

Comment: Let me post my GetProductsRequest . Can you try with using my GetProductsRequest in your sample. Because I get issue when I use that class

Comment: If I remove XMLElement attribute from GetProductRequest for the property Persons and make it as XMLArrayItem attribute, things are fine.

May I know why this XMLElement attribute cause the value type de-serialization issue?

Answer (score 0):

> This only happens when I have XmlSerializerFormat for any one of my method in the service contract(GetProducts in this case).

In this case WCF uses `XmlSerializer` to serialize the data. Hence neither `[DataContract]` nor `[DataMember]` apply. If you really must use `XmlSerializer`, and need to further control XML serialization, you need to use its specific attributes, e.g. `[XmlElement]`, `[XmlAttrribute]`, `[XmlIgnore]`. It's a good practice to be explicit, to avoid hard-to-discover problems arising from unintentional renames of fields or properties:

```
public class Person
{
    [XmlElement("Id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore] // don't tell the stranger
    public Sex Sex { get; set; }
}
```

Also note that `[Serializable]` attribute has nothing to do with XML serialization and data contract serialization. Its related to *binary* serialization *only*.

Comment: I have 2 questions.
I want xmlserialization in getproducts (which works fine) but datacontractserialization in saveproducts. How can i achieve this than?
So Shouldn't I use both serializaiton type in operation contract level in the same service contract?

Comment: It is not necessary to mark them with attributes, nor to use properties. "element" is assumed, and fields work fine - that is **fully** supported.

Comment: Decorate your members with both attributes for XML serializer and for data contract serializer.

Comment: I have decorated with both [Serializable] and [DataContract]. But still value types are not getting deserialzed. Why I want to use two serialization type is GetProducts is old code and using xmlattribute. But saveproduct is new requirement which should be using datacontractserialization

Comment: @MarcGravell Huh, need another cup of coffee… It's too early to answer on SO :-) Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 0):

Is your service contract decorated with the `ServiceContract` attribute:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IServices
{
    // ...
}
```

I just hope you are not showing us something different here.

Comment: Yes I do have ServiceContract. Edited it now. Thanks

Comment: @Al.Net you can see, though - it makes it hard for us to be looking at the right thing if these details are omitted ;)